# 大容量トラフィックに耐えられるnotification機能はどう実装した方がいいですか。

Tags: notification

各種通知をクライアント側に送信したいです。

なるべく**WebサーバーとDBサーバーに負荷をかけない仕様**が望ましい。

※通知サーバーを別途構築することも考えています。

**シンプルかつ安全なサーバーの構成やミドルウェア、通知の仕様**について経験者の意見を聞きたいです。
よろしくおねがい致します。

Comment: 前提としているクライアントの条件をもう少し書いたほうが回答しやすいです

Comment: kilhyungdooさんのやりたいこと（システムの要件）をもっと教えていただけると助かります。想定しているサーバーやクライアントの条件や、「大容量」とは具体的にどれくらいのトラフィックなのかを教えてください。問題を具体的にシェアすると、良い解決策が見つかりやすいと思います。ヘルプセンターの「良い質問をするには」をご参考にされるとよいと思います。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: サーバー側は言語と環境には特に指定はなく幅広いアーキテクチャーから検討しようと思っています。クライアントは主にWebブラウザからアクセスを想定しています。説明不足ですみませんでした。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

詳細な条件がわからないので
通知=メッセージ、負荷をかけない=キューがよくできている
という風に捉えて、回答しておきます。

自前運用なら [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) あたりが定番かつ良い評判をよく聞きます。
AWS が可なら [AmazonSQS](http://aws.amazon.com/jp/sqs/) とかも選択肢に入るとは思いますが、
通知条件・方法次第ではニーズに合致しないかもしれません。

Answer (score 3):

環境が指定されていないので、実際の実装の参考程度に。。。

ASP.NETの機能にSignalRがあります。
仕組み的にはWebSocket等を利用してサーバー側がクライアント側に設定してあるJavascriptのメソッドをキックするというものです。

[公式のIntroduction(www.asp.net)](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)や[実際にチャットアプリを作る記事(gihyo.jp)](http://gihyo.jp/dev/serial/01/realtimeweb/0005)などが参考になるでしょうか。